# Wordpress display parent category as heading with children underneath

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, categories

I have a grandparent category set up with children and grandchildren like this:

1. Grandparent Cat

   - Child Cat 01

     - Grandchild Cat 01
     - Grandchild Cat 02
     - Grandchild Cat 03
   - Child Cat 02

     - Grandchild Cat 01
     - Grandchild Cat 02
     - Grandchild Cat 03

I want to loop through these on a main Grandparent category page and show each child heading, with grandchildren links underneath.

So far I have this which is showing all children and grandchildren, but not differentiating between the two...

```
        <?php

        $this_category = get_category($cat);

        $args = (array (
            'orderby'=> 'id',
            'depth' => '1',
            'show_count' => '0',   
            'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID,
            'echo' => '0'
        )); 

        $categories = get_categories( $args );
        
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 

            echo $category->name
        
        } ?>
```

I need a rule for if has children...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively simple to identify by checking if the category has a parent

```
<?php

    $this_category = get_category($cat);

    $args = (array (
        'orderby'=> 'id',
        'depth' => '1',
        'show_count' => '0',   
        'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID,
        'echo' => '0'
    )); 

    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
       if (!$category->parent) {
           echo 'Has no parent';
       }

       echo $category->name;
    
    } ?>
```

Alternatively a recursive approach, depending on what you need

```
<?php
$this_category = get_category($cat);

function category_tree(int $categoryId = 0) {
  $categories = get_categories([
    'parent' => $categoryId,
    'echo' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'show_count' => 0
  ]);

  if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) { 
      echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>';
          echo $category->name;
          
          category_tree($category->term_id);
    }
  }

  echo '</li></ul>';
}

category_tree($this_category->cat_ID);
```

Comment: Altho I'd like to be able to add more markup to the grandchildren and not sure how to go about this here.

Comment: @user144271 to specifically target them you could use CSS child selectors i.e. `ul > li > li` or if you need classes specifically then you'd need to write in some logic to this around that - probably best to post a new question if you get stuck specifically on a certain aspect :)